# jqGrid footer filter text

Tags: jqgrid, footer

Is there a way where in i can display something like: "Filtered 20 records out of 30" where 30 is the total count of records in my jqGrid footer???

Answer (score 0):

You need to set de property `viewrecords:true` in the jqgrid. Check de documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid).

"**viewrecords**:Defines whether we want to display the number of total records from the query in the pager bar"

Comment: @apoorvabade pick one of the answers as the Accepted Answer if they helped you.....